# Output from Meta Box Array

Tags: metabox, loop, array

I have created a meta box and it's storing the post data successfully but I am having trouble outputting the content and displaying it in a sensible fashion - beyond my limited knowledge of PHP. I am a bee-keeper and want to record inspections of my beehives - so for each hive there is a record with a set number of fields.

So I want to loop through the colony array for all hives, i.e. until $hive is empty, and output the data in the form of a table with 1 row per hive. Currently I have managed to manually produce the first row of the table but don't know how to set-up a loop that could do it for me.

```
<?php if (have_posts() ):?>

        <?php while ( have_posts() ) :the_post();?>
    <?php
    $meta=$simple_mb->the_meta();
     // need a loop here until all instances colony are reached 
        $hive = $meta['colony'] [0]['hive']; 
                $queen = $meta['colony'] [0]['cb_ex4_cb'];
        $bias = $meta['colony'] [0]['cb_ex4_bias'];
        $brood = $meta['colony'] [0]['cb_ex4_bcom'];
        $stores = $meta['colony'] [0]['stores'];
        $mycomm = $meta['colony'] [0]['comment'];
        $plan = $meta['colony'] [0]['plan'];
    ?>

            <table id="anytable" summary="Colony Inspections" cellspacing="0">
            <caption>        < ?php echo   $inspect;?> 
            <?php       the_title(); ?></caption>           
            <tbody>

    <tr>        <!-- want additional rows added for each colony -->
    <th scope="row"><?php echo $hive; ?></th> 
    <td><div><?php echo $queen; ?></div></td>
    <td><div><?php echo $brood; ?></div></td>
    <td><div><?php echo $stores; ?></div></td>
    <td><?php echo $mycomm; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $plan; ?></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>


    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: What's `$simple_mb->the_meta()`? It's a custom or plugin function, but you need to tell from where it is and how it works. Btw: You'll have to replace `get_post_custom()` with your fn in my example. But for later readers I leave the answer with a native WP function.

Answer (score 2):

### Add meta data as "flat" data to the post

The actual problem is, that your meta data comes back as array (with a single entry), when calling `get_post_custom( $id );` for your post. Here's a simple function, that adds all meta data attached to a post to your post object.

```
/**
 * Merges custom/meta data with post data
 * 1) get_post_custom() is cached from the WP_Query
 * 2) The following line gets the first element from each meta array as it's only a single value
 * It then merges the resulting flattened Array with the post object that gets casted to another Array
 * 
 * @param array $query
 * @return array result 
 */
public function add_meta_data( $query )
{
    foreach ( $query as $post )
        $result[] = array_merge( 
             array_map( 'array_shift', get_post_custom( $post->ID ) )
            ,(array) $post 
        );

    return $result;
}
```

#### How-to use

We then run the loop simply wrapped in a `<table>`. You can add your `<thead><th>etc.` before and the `<tfoot>etc.` afterwards. Then just echo all your `<tr><td>Cell</td>etc.` inside the loop.

```
// Before your loop:
global $wp_query;
// Merge the queried posts with their meta data, using our custom template tag/function
$query = add_meta_data( $wp_query->posts );

echo "<table>";
// Loop through our new query array
foreach ( $query as $post )
{
        // This extracts your post object, so you don't have to save them in separate vars
        // @see @link http://php.net/manual/de/function.extract.php
        extract( $post, EXTR_SKIP );

        echo "<tr>";
        // Then simply call all your meta data like this:
        echo "<td>{$hive}</td>";
        // Then add other meta data here:
        echo "<td>{$whatever}</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Seems to fail on the  while ($query->have_posts() ) -  gives an error message (shortened) - CALL TO A MEMBER FUNCTION HAVE_POSTS() ON A NON-OBJECT. A print_r of $query shows that it is holding all the post data. Andy ideas on how to overcome the error?

Comment: Sorry meant to say that the error is on "if ($query->have_posts() ){" -  gives an error message (shortened) - CALL TO A MEMBER FUNCTION HAVE_POSTS() ON A NON-OBJECT. A print_r of $query shows that it is holding all the post data. Andy ideas on how to overcome the error?

Comment: Ok, you're better off with a `foreach` loop.

Comment: (see edit of the answer for a `foreach` example)

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this...

```
// need a loop here until all instances colony are reached 

foreach( $meta['colony'] as $colony ){
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach( $colony as $key => $value ){
        //$key may contain 'cb_ex4_cb'
        //$value may contain what you put in $queen
        echo '<td>$value</td>'; 
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks - the foreach code is working and outputting the results. Now I just need to sort out the formatting of the data into a table, which is bit more involved and will take a bit of time.